# Why does my pan gesture only recognize the event after the second input?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uigesturerecognizer, uipangesturerecognizer

I have a pan gesture set up, but in order for the gesture to actually recognize my input I need to actually make contact with the screen and drag my finger two times. When I'm initially dragging my finger in the direction that should trigger the pan gesture, nothing happens. Only after I release my finger and try again does the gesture actually work.

I've done some debugging and I placed an `NSLog` statement before any of the if-statements I use in the pan gesture, and as I thought nothing shows up when I initially drag my finger. But when I drag my finger the second time, I can see the text I put into the `NSLog`.

This is really strange, and I'm pretty sure this didn't always happen but I have no idea what I could have done to make it like this? Any suggestions? I could provide some code if that would help, but I don't really know what code I should post since this problem doesn't seem to be coming from the gesture itself, but rather how the app recognizes the gesture.

under implementation:

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * panGestureToHome;
```

view did load:

```
panGestureToHome = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(swipeToHomePan:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:panGestureToHome];
```

Comment: could you post some code as to what you're trying? Where are you attaching the pan gesture recognizer to your view?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind it was my mistake. I had two pan gestures for the same view with different functions. All I had to do was just move the second pan gesture above the main one.